# Stop doxygen (in some directories) for recursive input

Tags: documentation, comments, doxygen

I've used this tuto (http://www.duckrowing.com/2010/03/18/documenting-objective-c-with-doxygen-part-ii/) to create my documentation... I would like to run doxygen in some directories and not in others! The problem is that I don't want to reorganize all the directories! Is it possible to put a file in the directories I don't want doxygen to run into?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used the OSX frontend, but in a doxygen config file, you can specify the INPUT tag and give a list of pathnames.  You can also use INPUT to select a wide swath of directories and then use EXCLUDE to exclude specific directories.

Check out http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html and look at the INPUT tag.  There's probably an expert mode in the GUI to enter this, or you can just edit the doxygen config file by hand.